# Have experience in planning

Tags: meaning-in-context, idioms, prepositional-phrases, transitivity

I have a sentence with a gap :

> I have experience ___.

**A.for  planning**

**B.planning**

**C.with planning**

**D.on planning smth**

Could anyone advise me what to put into the gap, please. All four options sound natural for me and I can not find any rules with regard to task. I suspect that the choice strongly depends on the context. Is it so?

Comment: Of your options, only C fits. My preference would be: *experience of planning* but this is not an option. The choice of prepositions is always hard work for learners of a language as there are few helpful rules.

Comment: @RonaldSole, so how did you make such a choice of preposition? Was it just because you are a native speaker?

Comment: I would not say "experience of planning" but "planning experience" or "experience planning" or "experience in planning" or "experience with planning".

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov As you see, native speakers don't necessarily agree. I think that prepositions are simply learned and that the choice depends largely on context and preference, as in: experience in coaching sport, experience with children, experience of  war.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all of your possibilities the understanding would be the same

> I have experience *planning* a wedding.
>   I have experience *for planning* a wedding.
>   I have experience *with planning* a wedding.
>   I have experience *on planning* a wedding.
>
> I have experience *in planning* a wedding.

that you have planned wedding before.

Which to use is more a matter of style.